# Simple.OData how to consume json?

Tags: json, odata, simple.odata

I am currently consuming OData in a Xamarin App - and there is a significant performance issue on devices older than the iPhone 5. I believe it is because a simple request returns a significant amount of Xml - which has to be parsed by the phone.
Using Json cuts the payload size to 1/10th.

*(note: I am referring to the fact it will reduce the amount of work that the client library has to do, not the fact it will transfer over the network more quickly)*

How can I turn on Json in Simple.OData? Xml is basically unusable on iPhone 4.

Thanks

Comment: I've since pulled out the Simple.OData for making the actual request, and now just use RestSharp.MonoTouch. I still use Simple.OData for formulating the request URI - so that I can keep using all my Linq queries... I just dont actually execute it - I grab the URI from GetCommandTextAsync, and pass that to ReshSharp. Increased my App's performance 10x! I will, however, eagerly await Simple.OData json support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON support has been added to Simple.OData.Client 4.0. It should work fine now.

Comment: Hi Vagif, do you have any idea of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497535/adding-jsessionid-in-request-header

Comment: How do you enable that?
I'm getting an XmlException when querying with SOC, saying `System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'`. ([StackTrace](https://zerobin.net/?699886c22b165924#q0yqNyoOZSVmZPgzSf8qMBykLxaVm88+X/Cto9Skf1k=))

Answer (score 0):

According to OData Protocol, add the following in http header will enable server using Json format:
`Accept:application/json`

Or add the $format in url like following:

`BaseUrl\Customers?$format=application/json`

Comment: Please note the specific question "How can I turn on Json in Simple.OData". Simple.OData needs to not only ask the server for Json, but be able to understand, and parse the response.